# PicklingError in a python code in Sympy module

Tags: python, pickle, sympy

I wrote the following code but I got a Pickling error. I don't know what is the mistake.

```
    x = Symbol('x')
    y = Symbol('y')

    f = Function('f')(x)
    h = Function('h')(x)

    g = Function('g')(y)
    t = Function('t')(y)
    X1 = f + g
    X2 = h * t
    E = 1 + (f.diff(x)) ** 2 + (f.diff(x) * g) ** 2
    F = f.diff(x) * g.diff(y) + f.diff(x) * g.diff(y) * f * g
    G = 1 + (g.diff(y)) ** 2 + (f * g.diff(y)) ** 2

   MainD = 2 * (E * G - F ** 2)
   with open('M.pickle', 'wb') as outf:
   outf.write(pickle.dumps(MainD))
```

I got the following error message:

```
   Can not pickle f: it is not the same object as _main_ .f
```

Comment: please mention what type of picklng error you got. Also providing a errortrace is helpful in finding the problem.

Comment: @Mani I added the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one of `pickle` or even `dill` have a complete compatibility with `Sympy`. But, you can convert the output to a string and after that write/read from a txt file. The following is an example based on your codes.

```
Str_MainD = str(MainD)
with open('M.py', 'w') as file:
    file.write(Str_MainD)
```

Now, by

```
with open('M.py', 'r') as file:
    Read_From_File = file.read()
```

you can read it in another script (if the second script is manipulated by some `Simpy` codes, use `eval(file.read())`instead).